# E/cocos2d-x: cocos2d: warning, Director::setProjection() failed because size is 0

Tags: javascript, java, c++, android-studio, cocos2d-x

I am new to cocos creator. I am working on a game.
When running this on android studio an error comes on logcat.

```
11-21 11:58:02.373 588-12864/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to kill 1 processes for processgroup 17650
11-21 11:58:03.944 23317-23317/? E/SysUtils: ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
11-21 11:58:03.967 23317-23317/? E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
11-21 11:58:03.967 23317-23317/? E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
11-21 11:58:07.406 23401-23432/com.cocos2d.dufong E/cocos2d-x: cocos2d: warning, Director::setProjection() failed because size is 0
11-21 11:58:07.928 23401-23458/com.cocos2d.dufong E/cocos2d-x: cocos2d: warning, Director::setProjection() failed because size is 0
11-21 11:58:08.433 23401-23458/com.cocos2d.dufong A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x4bb2 in tid 23458 (GLThread 827)
11-21 11:58:08.535 192-192/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
11-21 11:58:08.535 192-192/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/razor/flo:6.0.1/MOB30X/3036618:user/release-keys'
11-21 11:58:08.535 192-192/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
11-21 11:58:08.535 192-192/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
11-21 11:58:08.536 192-192/? A/DEBUG: pid: 23401, tid: 23458, name: GLThread 827  >>> com.cocos2d.dufong <<<
11-21 11:58:08.536 192-192/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x4bb2
11-21 11:58:08.561 192-192/? A/DEBUG:     r0 941e7384  r1 941e6fd4  r2 00000000  r3 00004b9e
11-21 11:58:08.561 192-192/? A/DEBUG:     r4 941e7384  r5 941e7010  r6 941e7384  r7 941e74ac
11-21 11:58:08.561 192-192/? A/DEBUG:     r8 941e72fc  r9 00000011  sl 00005611  fp 941e7640
11-21 11:58:08.561 192-192/? A/DEBUG:     ip 00000000  sp 941e6fc8  lr a05f8b38  pc a05f7e00  cpsr 800b0010
11-21 11:58:08.566 192-192/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
11-21 11:58:08.566 192-192/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00e18e00  /data/app/com.cocos2d.dufong-2/lib/arm/libcocos2djs.so
11-21 11:58:09.537 192-192/? A/DEBUG: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_06
```

Problem : 
If i press home button and open game again, it is crashed.

How can i solve it? Any Suggestions.

Comment: show crash log ?

Comment: I have added logcat.

Comment: Did you find the solution to this?

Comment: @AayushAnand I don't remind that, I am not working on this project anymore. :)